# lilo: display boot (append) option for entry in boot menu

Tags: boot-loader, lilo

When my machine boots, lilo menu appears with different boot options. I can either select option, or wait for default option to boot automatically.

Now, I would like to have the possibility select a boot option, and change the kernel command line parameters (what is defined in the `append` line).

In `syslinux` (a different boot loader), when I am presented with the menu, I can move to desired item in the menu and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and the append line appears on the command line so that I can edit it.

How can I to do the same in `lilo`?

Below is my `lilo.conf`:

```
boot=/dev/sda
root=/dev/sda1
map=/boot/map

lba32

prompt
timeout=50

default=Linux

image=/boot/vmlinuz
    label=Linux
    read-only
    append="rootfstype=ext4 net.ifnames=0 loglevel=4 console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 3"
```

Comment: try GRUB instead of LILO if you want to have interactivity at boot time

Comment: Been forever since I've seen/used lilo... so +1 on "migrate to GRUB".

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but I specifically want to do this in `lilo`. Changing to `grub` is not a satisfactory solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, anything you type after on the `boot:` line after the name of the LILO boot option you want gets appended to the kernel command line. For example, since your LILO boot label is `Linux`, the classic way to boot into single user mode would be:

```
boot: Linux single
```

Unfortunately you cannot view or change the existing kernel command line defined to each LILO boot option: LILO is too minimalist for that.

Comment: are you sure that it is impossible to edit the existing kernel command line ?